# Quantization of spontaneously broken theory, which is not in the true vacuum

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, vacuum, symmetry-breaking

I wonder whether the source $J$ in QFT can make one to quantize the field when the system is in the excursion to the minimum. Precisely, I want to know that following process makes sence.

> Suppose, I have a real scalar $\phi^4$ theory, which originally has
> $\mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetry but it is spontaneously broken. So, when $t<0$,  the
> minimum of potential is at $\langle\phi \rangle =0$ as described by
> the following lagrangian,
>
> $$\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}\phi)^2 -\frac{\lambda}{4}\phi^4,$$ where $\lambda>0.$
>
> But the mass term suddenly turns on at $t=0$,
>
> $$\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}\phi)^2 +\frac{m^2}{2}\phi^2 -\frac{\lambda}{4}\phi^4,$$ where $m^2>0$ and $\lambda>0$.
>
> So the minimum of potential is now at $\langle \phi \rangle = m/\sqrt{\lambda} $.
>
> Then the expectation value of the field should move from the $0$ to
> the $ m/\sqrt{\lambda}$ during some finite time. I will denote the
> expactation value of $\phi$ at time t as $\langle\phi(t)\rangle$.
>
> Then I want to quantize the $\phi$ field about the
> $\langle\phi(t)\rangle$. To do this, I expand the potential about the
> $\langle\phi(t)\rangle$,
>
> $$V(\phi)=V(\langle\phi(t)\rangle)+ \frac{dV(\phi)}{d\phi}
>  \Big|_{\phi=\langle\phi(t)\rangle} \eta  +\frac{1}{2!}
>  \frac{d^2V(\phi)}{d\phi^2} \Big|_{\phi=\langle\phi(t)\rangle} \eta^2
>  +\frac{1}{3!} \frac{d^3V(\phi)}{d\phi^3} \Big|_{\phi=\langle\phi(t)\rangle} \eta^3 +\frac{1}{4!}
>  \frac{d^2V(\phi)}{d\phi^4} \Big|_{\phi=\langle\phi(t)\rangle} \eta^4,$$
>
> where $\eta=\phi-\langle\phi(t)\rangle$. This is similar procedure one
> does in the spontaneously broken theory, but the difference is that I
> expanded the potential not in the potential minimum. So $\frac{dV(\phi)}{d\phi} \Big|_{\phi=\langle \phi(t)\rangle}$ is not $0$
> here.
>
> To get usual Klein gordon equation, I turn on the source term $J
> > \phi$. So the linear term in the potential becomes
>
> $$\left(\frac{dV(\phi)}{d\phi} \Big|_{\phi=\langle\phi(t)\rangle} +J \right)\eta $$
>
> and I manipulate $J$ to exactly cancel the linear term. Finally I get
> $\phi^4$ theory without a linear term and theory looks the same as if
> it is in the minimum of the potential. Of course the mass or the
> self-interaction of the theory is time dependent.

Is this story really true?

Comment: I am not sure what your question is about. Are you asking if you can vanish the linear term about $\eta$ if you choose the appropriate external field $J$?

Comment: Hi thank you for the comment. More precicely, I want to quantize the phi field. But usually (as far as I know) such quantization is done when the phi is at the minimum (true vacuum). I want to understand how one can quantize the scalar field when it is during the excursion to the minimum.